# Rendering using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to react. I have some doubts regarding useState hooks.

**SCENARIO 1:**
Consider there are 3 custom tags. A,B,C. in the return();

```
return (
<>
<A />  
<B />  
<C />
</>
);
```

If there is some change in state of A, I know A will re-render but whether B and C will render again?
what will happens if B usestate is depended on usestate of A but C's usestate doesn't depend on any other state.

**SCENARIO 2:**
Consider two custom tags - parent and child.

```
<parent>
<child/>   //some definition 
</parent>
```

if there is change in state of parent will it render child again?
will it change in both the case when usestate of child is depended on parent usestate and child usestate not depended on parent' usestate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change in state will cause a re-render to a component and all of its child components.  To clarify your scenarios though:

**Scenario 1**

> what will happens if B usestate is depended on usestate of A:

if both states change, then both-render.  if A's changes, then B re-renders regardless.  if neither change, neither re-render.  if only B changes, then only B re-renders.

> but C's usestate doesn't depend on any other state.

if C's state is changing, it will re-render.

**Scenario 2**

> if there is change in state of parent will it render child again?

Yes

> will it change in both the case when usestate of child is depended on
> parent usestate:

if the parent's state is changing, the parent and the child will re-render.

> and child usestate not depended on parent' usestate.

in this case, if the parent state changes, the child re-renders regardless.  if parent does not change but child does, then only child re-renders.  if neither change, neither re-render.

There are ways around preventing a component to re-render using `useMemo` hooks, etc., but this is the default behavior.